# I am facing problem with executing a JavaScript file on Windows terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and my code is not executing. Wherever i searched it I realized the code has the correct syntax.
When i am running this code directly on terminal it is executing but when i made a file named hello.js and then executing, It is giving me error . The code and error are as follows respectively :

```
console.log('hello world');
```

Thrown:

```
node hello.js

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Make sure you are in the same folder as the file inside the terminal.

Comment: Also, is that the whole error message?

Comment: My file is saved on desktop. I got inside the desktop after that i tried to execute it but no luck!

Comment: Yes this is the whole error message appearing on terminal

Comment: Strange. Try `node hello`

Comment: Even that is giving the same error

Comment: Try typing just `node` in terminal. Check if that opens up a terminal.

Comment: Actually it worked. Thanks... I was re including the node package.